# How do I change a Checkbuttons state in TTK?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-button

I'm creating a list of Checkbuttons which highlight when selected, when another Checkbutton is selected I want to deselect the other buttons,

I have two buttons in my code when my button 'create booking' is toggled on or off it calls clear_previous_selection. Here I try and change the state of my other button 'viewFilmListing' to be un-highlighted although no matter what I set the state to it doesn't seem to want to unselect.

Here are some of my combinations and outputs:
[Film listing selected without create booking ever being selected (Terminal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8farR.png)
[Film listing selected without create booking ever being selected (GUI)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQOms.png)

[Create booking selected then Film listing selected after (Terminal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQPRh.png)
[Create booking selected then Film listing selected after (GUI)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/460VW.png)

[Film listing toggled on then off then Create booking selected (Terminal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33FZ8.png)
[Film listing toggled on then off then Create booking selected (GUI)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLEqa.png)

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sv_ttk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        sv_ttk.use_dark_theme()

        self.geometry('1200x800')
        self.title("Menu")
        self.resizable(0,0)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=0)

        rowCount = 0

        self.createBooking = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text="View film listing", style="Toggle.TButton",command=lambda : self.button_selection(0))
        self.createBooking.grid(column=0, row=rowCount, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
        rowCount+=1
        self.viewFilmListing = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text="Create booking", style="Toggle.TButton",command=lambda : self.button_selection(1))
        self.viewFilmListing.grid(column=0, row=rowCount, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
        

    def clear_previous_selection(self):
        print("We are clearing selections")
        print(self.viewFilmListing.state())
        self.viewFilmListing.configure(state='alternate')
        self.viewFilmListing.update_idletasks()

        
    def button_selection(self, option):
        if(option == 0): 
            print(0)       
            self.clear_previous_selection()
            #Call view film listing
            return
        elif(option == 1):
            print(1)
            #Call create booking
            return
        else:
            return

        
if __name__ =="__main__":
    app=App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I tried setting the state to 'disabled', this greys the button out and I can't de-disable it.

I've tried a few combinations of changing the state ('False', 0, '', 'alternate', 'normal'), hopefully my question is clear. None of the combinations stated above worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the state of the `Checkbutton` you can use :

```
.state(['!selected']) # clear the checkbox


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sv_ttk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        sv_ttk.use_dark_theme()

        self.geometry('1200x600')
        self.title("Menu")
        self.resizable(0,0)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=0)

        rowCount = 0

        self.createBooking = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text="View film listing", style="Toggle.TButton",command=lambda : self.button_selection(0))
        self.createBooking.grid(column=0, row=rowCount, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
        rowCount+=1
        self.viewFilmListing = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text="Create booking", style="Toggle.TButton",command=lambda : self.button_selection(1))
        self.viewFilmListing.grid(column=0, row=rowCount, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
        

    def clear_previous_selection(self):
        #print("We are clearing selections")
        self.viewFilmListing.state(['!selected'])
        
        #print(self.viewFilmListing.state())
        #self.viewFilmListing.configure(state='alternate')
        #self.viewFilmListing.update_idletasks()

        
    def button_selection(self, option):
        if(option == 0): 
            print(0)       
            self.clear_previous_selection()
            #Call view film listing
            return
        elif(option == 1):
            print(1)
            self.createBooking.state(['!selected'])
            #Call create booking
            return
        else:
            return

        
if __name__ =="__main__":
    app=App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is perfect, all working!

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sv_ttk


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(
            self
            ):
        super().__init__()
        sv_ttk.use_dark_theme()

        self.geometry('1200x800')
        self.title("Menu")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=0)
        self.createBookingVar = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.viewFilmListingVar = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.variables = [self.createBookingVar, self.viewFilmListingVar]
        rowCount = 0

        self.createBooking = ttk.Checkbutton(
            self,
            text="View film listing",
            style="Toggle.TButton",
            variable=self.createBookingVar,
            onvalue=True,
            offvalue=False,
            command=lambda: self.handle_button_click(self.createBookingVar)
            )
        self.createBooking.grid(column=0, row=rowCount, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
        rowCount += 1
        self.viewFilmListing = ttk.Checkbutton(
            self,
            text="Create booking",
            style="Toggle.TButton",
            variable=self.viewFilmListingVar,
            onvalue=True,
            offvalue=False,
            command=lambda: self.handle_button_click(self.viewFilmListingVar)
            )
        self.viewFilmListing.grid(column=0, row=rowCount, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

    def handle_button_click(self, variable: tk.BooleanVar):
        for var in self.variables:
            if var != variable:
                var.set(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

The solution is to use Tk variables. You could mask this *handle_button_click* function into some other as you please, but this should cover your use-case.